# How to tell Dash to look in specific folders for Videos and Music

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, search

I have 2 folders filled with videos and songs that reside in a second hard drive. How can I tell dash to look in those folders every time I am looking for videos or songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it searches ~/Music and ~/Video for those lenses.

The easist and most obvious solution is softlinking those folders to the second hard-drive.

The more complicated solution involves custom lenses.

Comment: Lol. True aking. Nice idea.